# windows authentication in asp.net login page form with admin and user credential authorization

Tags: asp.net

I'm new to asp.net. I've created one web application.
For that created the below page.
 1. user.aspx
 2. admin.aspx
 3. login.aspx(using windows credentials to redirect user.aspx)

Here, Login.aspx page authentication using windows credentials. login page contains user selection dropdownlistbox(user and admin options) and 2 text fields for username and password.

**conditions:**
1. if user selects admin and given credentials, it should redirect admin.aspx.

1. if user selects user and given credentials, it should redirect user.aspx.

I've tried the below code,

```
//web.config
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="user.aspx" loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Here my problem, if i select user option and given credentials, it can rediected to user.aspx page. But if i edit the url as Admin.aspx in address bar., it got redirected to admin.aspx.

It should not be redirect to admin.aspx(actually it is in user option). It should ask login credential for the admin.aspx.

can anyone suggest me what should i do??

**Note:** 
1. Here i'm not storing credentials in the database and all. using windows credentials using advapi32.dll.

1. Hardcoded admin user in the login.aspx.cs code page to redirect admin.aspx page depends on user selection in the login page.

Comment: What I get from your text is that there is no way to see if the user is logged in as an admin. What I get from it is that there's only a redirection to the desired page depending on the selection.

Comment: if all three files are in same folder ?

Comment: @Manoj: yes. all are in same folder.